# Store HTML form data in JS variable using jQuery serializeArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to use Javascript/jQuery to get data from a form and save the value to a variable. There is only a single text input and submit button in the form, and only one piece of data will need to be retrieved. I pieced together this code from examples online but it isn't giving me any output.

```
$("#submit").onclick = function() {

    var input = "";
    $("#binary-input").click(function() {
        var x = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.each(x, function(i, field) {
            input = field.value;
        });
    });

    console.log("Input: ");
    console.log(input);
}
```

A fix for my code is what I'm requesting, but a more efficient approach would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off jQuery doesn't have an 'onclick' event handler. You can either use 'click' (https://api.jquery.com/click/) like so:

```
$("#submit").click(function()...
```

Or use 'on' (https://api.jquery.com/on/) and specify the type of event you want to handle

This is what I'd normally do:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    // Get the input and its value
    var inputValue = $("#binary-input").val();

    // Output the value
    console.log(inputValue);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I confused it with JavaScript.